# Is there any emulator for testing my responsive website in windows phone (windows 8,windows 8.1 OS)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, yii, device

I have developed responsive site in Yii framework for iPhone, iPad, windows phone but now problem is that How 
do I testing my responsive site for windows phone (windows 8,windows 8.1 OS) with different resolutions ?

Is there any testing device for windows phone or emulator which I can test my website ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just download and install the Windows Phone SDK: https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

It comes bundled with emulators for all resolutions supported by Windows Phone: 480x800, 720p, 1080p, and 768x1280.

Comment: I had search alternate solution for testing my responsive site for windows phone and I found opera mobile emulator is it right way to test my responsive website for windows phone ?

Comment: @JineshGandhi Opera Mobile was available on Windows Mobile, but it has never been released on Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

Windows mobile has some very rare issues regarding responsive mobile websites. So it would be better for you to test it on a real device or an emulator. download the sdk and view your web in it by hosting it somewhere.